# Is there a way of safely pointing to a temporary value declared inside of a function?

Tags: c++, pointers

Consider the following code:

```
int * p;

void Set()
{
    int i = 7;
    p = & i; // potentially disastrous
}
```

I know that pointing to a value that may be overwritten is bad but I recall reading that there was a way to prevent a value such as i from being lost when declared and then pointed to in this way. I've scoured my text book but have had trouble finding the exact text elaborating on this and am starting to think I may have even imagined it. Is there a way of safely pointing to a temporary value declared inside of a function? A way of making the temporary value i no longer temporary?

Thanks for all your help in advance!

Comment: You could declare `i` as `static`, but then it's really no different than a global variable -- it just has more limited scope.

Comment: You imagined it (unless you're thinking of using dynamic memory)

Comment: give your function an `int` return value and return `i`.

Comment: @cdhowie Yeah, I recall a keyword like that being used...

Comment: Your variable `i` is not what's normally called a "temporary". It's local to `Set()` -- or, in Standardese, it's an object with automatic storage duration. There is such a thing as "temporary storage duration", introduced in C11, but it applies only to an odd corner case involving arrays within structs or unions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I recall reading that there was a way to prevent a value such as i from being lost when declared and then pointed to in this way

The closest thing to what you mention (if I understood your sentence correctly) is the rule which allows prolonging the lifetime of a *temporary* when bound to a *reference* (§ 12.2/5 of the C++11 Standard):

```
struct X { int x = 0; };
X foo() { return X(); }
int main()
{
    X const& x = foo(); // The lifetime of the object bound to x is prolonged
    x.x = 42; // This is OK
}
```

However, **there is no such rule for pointers nor for objects that are not temporaries**.

> A way of making the temporary value i no longer temporary?

In your example, `i` is **not** a temporary: it is an object with *automatic storage duration*. A temporary is an object whose life-time (usually) terminates at the end of the full expression that creates it (with the exception mentioned above and a few more listed in § 12.2/4-5).

Comment: But i is an integer, not an object

Comment: @user1800967: In C++ terminology, everything is an "object" - although it is true that in OOP the term "object" is usually meant to denote instances of class types.

Comment: Everything is an object?.. Oh man, gonna have to read up on that later then!

Comment: @user1800967: Well, using the terminology of the C++ Standard, then yes: an object is defined to be a region of storage. Apart from this, objects are given other properties, such as duration, type, name, etc. The type of an object can be `int`, `double`, or `std::string`, or `X` (etc.). What you probably mean when you think "object" are objects whose type is a class type.

Answer (score 2):

taking const ref to an temporary extends liifetime of this temporary up to the end of scope of this const reference, however in your example you are not taking address of temporary but local automatic object `i`.

so to extends lifetime of temporary do simply:

```
const int& iref=int(3);
    int a= iref;
    //..do stuff with iref, i.e:
    printf("iref: %d\n", a);
```

output:

> iref: 3
>
> RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 46ms)

Answer (score 1):

The value of `i` has to reside in memory somewhere. If you declare it inside a function, it is likely to be allocated on the stack and will be lost when the function returns. If you really need the value to always be constant like in your example, then what you need is to declare it outside the function as static const:

```
int * p;
static const int i = 7;

void Set()
{
    p = & i;
}
```

If this is not what you need, maybe you can elaborate a bit on your very minimal example code so that we can better understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I just wanted to know if there was a way of preventing i from being lost. This way, having a pointer point to it would be rendered safe.

Comment: This way it is safe both from being deallocated and also from having its value overwritten by other code. I just don't understand why you want a pointer to an integer that never changes value. Maybe there is a completely different way to solve your underlying problem, whatever it is.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `static` keyword.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *p;

void set() {
    static int x = 7;
    p = &x;
}

int main(){
    set();
    printf("%d", *p);
}
```

correctly prints 7.

however, I would strongly discourage using such a piece of code in anything but a research on the static keyword and pointers.

Comment: Yes: I'm doing this for research purposes. I'm in the process of getting acquainted with the C++ language (moving over from Java)